# Getting error of modules not found on linux

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting below error when running `ng build` command on Linux however it successfully build on Windows environment. Below are the error I'm getting

> ERROR in app/app.module.ts(23,5): Error during template compile of
>   'AppModule'
>
> Could not resolve ./iteminquiry/iteminquiry.component relative to
>   /u/CDI/Dynamo/web/angular/src/app/app.module.ts..
>
> src/app/iteminquiry/editItemInquiry.component.ts(4,36): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module './iteminquiry.service'.
>
> src/app/app.module.ts(7,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   './iteminquiry/iteminquiry.component'.
>
> src/app/app.module.ts(11,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   './pipes/filter.pipe'.
>
> src/app/iteminquiry/itemInquiry.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module './iteminquiry.service'.
>
> src/app/iteminquiry/itemInquiry.component.ts(6,33): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module '../pipes/filter.pipe'.

Comment: Maybe you should first run "npm i" for installing required files?

Comment: I already run the command

Comment: npm install successfully run but got error on below command

Comment: [Piush@dev /u/CDI/Dynamo/web/angular]$ ng build --prod --base-href /CD/gui/